# Convergence of a CDF to another CDF

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, continuity

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables. Further, suppose that $Z := X + cY$ is also a random variable for all constants $c > 0$. If we assume that the corresponding cdfs $F_X$ and $F_Z$ are continuous at all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ how does one formally show that
>
> $$F_Z(a) \to F_X(a) \quad \text{as}~ c \to 0.$$

To start, we can write

$$\lim_{c \to 0}F_Z(a) = \lim_{c \to 0}\mathbb{P}(X + cY \leq a).$$

But I don't think we can use any of the usual inequalities here... so I'm a little lost on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to show is $$\int F_X(a - cy) \mathrm{d}F_Y(y) \rightarrow F_X(a).$$

Pick $\epsilon > 0$, find $\overline{y}>0$ such that $$\int_{(-\infty, -\overline{y}) \cup (\overline{y}, \infty)} \mathrm{d}F_Y(y) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Pick $\delta > 0$ such that $|F_X(a + x) - F_X(a)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $|x| < \delta$. Then, for any $c$ such that $|c| < \frac{\delta}{\overline{y}}$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\int |F_X(a - cy) - F_X(a)| \mathrm{d}F_Y(y) \\
\leq &\int_{(-\infty, -\overline{y}) \cup (\overline{y}, \infty)} \mathrm{d}F_Y(y) + \int_{[-\overline{y}, \overline{y}]} |F_X(a - cy) - F_X(a)| \mathrm{d}F_Y(y) \\
< & \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon.
\end{align*}

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't even think to take the convolution...